# Spring batch and Kubernetes cron job

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cron, spring-batch

I am trying to configure a Spring batch job triggered through Kubernetes cron job. I configured job, partition and steps. The job could be triggered through Kubernetes cron job.

The spring boot application uses CommandlineRunner and JobLauncher to launch the job. The issue is when the job completes, the status is updated to "Completed" in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table. But the POD status is still "Running" and not "Completed".

Due to this the POD is not removed and keep on piling on each execution. This happens though I have configured failedJobsHistoryLimit and successfulJobsHistoryLimit to 1.  When I call System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context)) in the main application class, the status of the job in the table is not updated to "Completed" due to IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed exception.

The status was still "Started". But the status of the POD becomes completed and upon each run, the previous POD is deleted automatically due to the failed and successful job history configurations.

Is there any way to exit the application gracefully with all status updates?

Comment: If you just run the job runner locally, does it exit on its own?  Does your Job contain just the one container?  Does your cluster have anything installed such as Istio that might cause an extra container to be injected?  If you can [edit] the question to contain a [mcve] that might help understand what's going on more concretely.

Comment: There is only one container running in the POD which is the spring batch. After completion of the job, the display is as \n                                                          testjob-28273274-5nhng      1/1     Running     0               31h

Comment: The same code can execute outside Kubernetes and shutdown hook is called and the batch job could terminate.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be the case if the Spring Boot app exits when the job is finished. A typical case for that behaviour is having a web dependency in the classpath which results in having servlet container still waiting for requests even after the job is finished. Another common cause is a having a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean that should be shutdown explicitly (otherwise the app will continue to run even after the job is finished).

Comment: Logged into the POD and listed the running processes listening to different ports. `java 1 root 187u IPv6 375793717 0t0 TCP job2-28278761-4wdl9:39054->kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443 (ESTABLISHED)`   and  `java 1 root 188u IPv6 376503245 0t0 TCP job2-28278761-4wdl9:51064->mysql-router-svc.abc-dao.svc.cluster.local:3306 (ESTABLISHED)` The batch job is calling other services within the cluster so need to do service discovery and using resttemplate to call other service. @mahmoudbenhassine these connections preventing the application from shutting down?

Comment: If you use resttemplate then you night have a web dependency in the classpath, making spring boot start a servlet container, which will still run and prevent the app from exiting after the job is finished. You can check that from the logs of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot get the control back in the main method, I called jobrepository.update(execution) in afterJob method in the ExecutionListenerclass. This helped to update the status of job. After this, I called  System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context)); This made the application exit and the POD belonging to the previous trigger was deleted.